# How to automatic combine data from multiple google sheets to another google sheet by GOOGLE APPS SCRIPT

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, report

Everyday I have to manually do a report with the data got from multiple google sheets (all have one sheet with the same number of columns) to another google sheet (just have 1 sheet as well). I loaded all of the google sheets and then copy and paste one by one to the report. So I would like to ask you how to automatic do this progress by GOOGLE APPS SCRIPT. If there are any way to get the data without loading the google sheets is great. Ex: I have the link of stage profit such as VIC profit, NSW profit, QLD profit, etc. (I'm in Australia) and I need to report of national profit. Could you please advise me?

Much appreciate your advice.

Phuc.

Comment: rather than copy and paste use the function importrange() to get data in the single sheet

Comment: Or indirect() and build the links to each named sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can open another "file" with `SpreadsheetApp.openById()`. And from there you can use its sheets, data, everything.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid

```
var ss_current = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ss_remote = SpreadsheetApp.openById("abc1234567");

var values = ss_remote
  .getSheetByName("Expenses")
  .getRange('A1:C')
  .getValues();
```

and you can insert it here

Comment: Hi Molnár, thank you kindly for your help :))